# Rocksdb cache store in infinispan - huge size of .log file

Tags: infinispan, rocksdb

I am using embedded infinispan cache 14 and rocksdb cache store for persistence. After couple of hours, I observed .log file in cache store if getting huge in size.

I have searched on it and used below configuration in infinispan cache config. but no improvement.

32
32768000

and block-size="64000" cache-size="10240000" in persistence xml.

Could anybody guide me on same?